# Generate UITouch event from an app in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uitouch, generate

Is it possible to generate a UITouch event, from an iOS 11 app, which will never be submitted to the App Store?

I've seen several articles, dating back to around 2010 describing some old methods of doing this which are no longer valid.  Does anyone know of a way to do this in iOS 11?

This app would never be submitted to the app store, it would only be used for UI testing of a second app so that this second app would not have to include hooks from some 3rd party test framework such as Squish.

Edit: I should add that the UI testing to be done will use a camera pointed at the a physical phone and then we want to be able to, remotely from a PC, generate simulated touches on the phone at specific screen coordinates based on where different UI elements are located using some machine vision.  So it's not strictly a software only setup, we have physical hardware in the loop.

Comment: UI Testing already allows you to tap a button, so what do you need this extra UITouch for? When the UI test taps the button, there will be a touch as usual.

Comment: It has to be able to work on a physical iPhone, with any arbitrary app.  Basically we will be pointing a camera at the phone and then want to be able to, remotely from a PC, generate simulated touches on the phone at specific screen coordinates based on where different UI elements are located using some machine vision.